# How to use query results as conditional in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

**I have the following `SELECT` query that looks to if there are records that meet the given criteria:**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(' SELECT (`Active`)
                         FROM `Table1` 
                         WHERE `Name` = ":name" AND Active <> Yes ');
$stmt->execute([
    'name' => $_POST['name']
]);
```

**If results of `Active` could either be a `No` or just no results. If the results are a No then the following query should run:**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `Table1`
                        SET `active` = `Yes` 
                        WHERE `Name` = `:name`');
$stmt->execute([
    'name' => $_POST['name']
]);
```

**If the results of the `SELECT` query does not find anything then the following query should run:**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(' INSERT INTO `Table1` (`Name`,`Active`)
                         VALUES (:name, :active ) ');
$stmt->execute([
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'active' => $_POST['active']
]);
```

How can this conditional be written?

I specifically do not want to set a unique constraint to the name column and create stored procedures I need it to be done as a conditional described above.

Comment: `$stmt->rowCount()` is what you want

Comment: Yes for the initial query that will be the format of the results but how can the conditional itself be written in PHP?

Comment: Just do you select, fetch the data and do a `if...else` in php ? Eg. `$data = /*result of your select*/; if (count($data) === 0) { /* no result */ } else if ($data['Active'] === "No" { /* Active is no */ } else { /* other case */ })`

Comment: How do I assign the results of the select query to the variable $data?

Comment: That’s really rather the kind of question you should answer for yourself, by working through a tutorial on these basics …

Comment: Plus this is a duplicate of your own previous question, [How to execute different queries based on results of conditional statement | PHP mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57207536/how-to-execute-different-queries-based-on-results-of-conditional-statement-php)

Comment: Race conditions bugs waiting to happing with this approach.. Add a unique key and use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) instead you can refactor all that code into one PHP prepare/execute and a single SQL query

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(' SELECT (`Active`)
                                 FROM `Table1` 
                                 WHERE `Name` = ":name" AND Active <> Yes ');
    $stmt->execute([
        'name' => $_POST['name']
    ]);

    if ($stmt->rowCount() === 0) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare(' INSERT INTO `Table1` (`Name`,`Active`)
                             VALUES (:name, :active ) ');
        $stmt->execute([
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'active' => $_POST['active']
        ]);
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `Table1`
                        SET `active` = `Yes` 
                        WHERE `Name` = `:name`');
        $stmt->execute([
            'name' => $_POST['name']
        ]);
    }
```

I have not tried this one out but it should work. Tell me if it doesnt.

Comment: Didn't think about that